# Texture painting - "Soften" brush doesn't work as expected in the Viewport

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, uv-image-editor, brushes

[image: Left side is smoothened using UV editor, and the right side using the Viewport]I can texture paint in Blender just fine, but the "soften" brush doesn't work as expected in the Viewport, it just blurs the color in an extremely subtle way. Meanwhile, when I use the "soften" brush in the UV editor, it blurs out the color nicely.

I've looked into this a little bit, and apparently there's a setting that is exclusive to the UV editor called "kernel radius", under Advanced brush settings. It's set to "2" in the UV editor, and reducing the radius to "1" produces a similar effect to the Viewport version of the "soften" brush, which is very subtle.

Phew, I hope that made sense. Since there's no option to increase "kernel radius" in the Viewport, I'm wondering how I can make the "soften" brush actually soften/blur the color out efficiently, without having to paint on the UV editor without X mirror. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind share your screenshot with UV and model so we can see the clear picture.

Comment: @TergTurry Sure, I just added it! Left side is smoothed out nicely using the UV editor, right side is smoothed out using the Viewport. The issue isn't the very inner portion of the mouth, (There are no faces there so its normal that there are artifacts there on the Viewport), the issue is the whole right side. As you can see the right bottom lip is still patchy, while the left bottom lip has evened out, for example.

Answer (score 2):

As I know we only have 2 options.

1. Zoom out and paint. When zoom out you will get stronger effect.
   [image]
   *Paint after zoom in (Left) and zoom out (Right)*
2. Decrease Spacing or switch Stroke Mothod to Dot
   [image]
   *Compare Spacing 1% (Left) and zoom out (Right)*

Change Blur Mode from Gaussian to [Box](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/tools.html) might also help.

Comment: Zooming out gave me the result I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @def you can accept the answer and mark it with a checkmark to show future readers that it's a correct answer and solved the problem.